# Snippet to copy product affiliate link to a custom field

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I had to migrate an affiliate store to another wordpress.
I need to copy the " product affiliate link " (woocommerce) in a custom field.

Something like:

```
foreach $products as $product {

 $mycustomfield($post->id, $customfieldname) =  $product->woocommerceaffiliatelink;

}
```

(I'm not a wordpress developer, the code above is just an example)

Comment: The code above is an example to what? This code is full of errors and I don't see how it's an example to what you want. As it stands WooCommerece is a third party plugin and is considered off-topic, you best ask this question on the WooCommerce forums.

Comment: So you're trying to read a value from a WooCommerce product? I don't think that's the correct syntax for that. And save it where? On the product's post object? Why not just use the existing WooCommerce field? Or on some other post? What's the relationship between the product and the post? Is it meant to be an array of values on the post for more than one product?

Comment: And AFAICR WooCommerce doesn't have affiliate links built in. Is that from an extra plugin too?

Comment: "I'm not a wordpress developer" - then hire one? Jokes aside, if you want to do it yourself, you need to dig in deeper. Where are these values stored right now? Which relation do they have? Can you do it in the DB alone? If not, what PHP should be executed?

Comment: I resolved this by myself. Thx anyway for the sarcasm.